# Determining method names of missing method calls

Tags: ruby

I have a class that executes special instructions based on missing method calls

```
class MyClass
  def method_missing(mname, *args)
    p mname
    nil
  end
end
```

Where doing the following....

```
obj = MyClass.new

obj.method1
```

will print out `:method1`

However, if I do something like this...

`obj.method1.method2`

I can't seem to define `method_missing` in a way where I can print out `:method2`

(NOTE: I must return nil in my method_missing method)

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Alright, what I'm actually trying to do is a bit weird, and I'm not sure it is possible, but here comes my attempt at explaining it.

I have a class like so:

```
class MyClass
  def method_missing(mname, *args)
    return some_var[mname]
  end
end
```

If `mc` was an instance of `MyClass`, I want to be able to call `mc.method` and get a particular object.

Now, I also want to be able to call `mc.method.some_other_method` where `some_other_method` is a method of the object returned by `mc.method`

Here's the tricky part: When `mc.method.some_other_method` is called, MyClass, written the way it is, suffices for my needs (i.e. I return the object, and the `some_other_method` is called). However, if just `mc.method` is called, I need to have something like this...

```
class MyClass
  def method_missing(mname, *args)
    #if ONLY mc.method
    some_var[mname].sanitize
    return some_var[mname]
  end
end
```

I know a solution to this is to just use the second version of MyClass and it should work for both cases (`mc.method` and `mc.method.some_other_method`) BUT, the thing is, I only NEED to call `sanitize` when `mc.method` is called, and not when `mc.method.some_other_method` is called. And sanitize is an extremely resource intensive method (I only want to call it if I absolutely need to).

With all that said, is there any solution, other than simply calling `sanitize` every time?

Comment: Jimmy, you said you must return nil.  If you'd like to elaborate on that it might help readers try to figure a way around the problem.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, building a query/SQL generator?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you could say "query generator" as an analogy (I'm querying the object for info), but this is definitely not a query/SQL generator.

Answer (score 0):

After update what you are trying to do started looking like ActiveRecord filter chain. It is designed to only query DB (call sanitize in your case) if there won't be any other chain calls (method2). Suddenly, there is no way in ruby to know if there will be anoter call, and when method returns, you never know what is going to happen with the result.

Trick that ActiveRecord uses to solve the problem is to return intermediate chain object, which will trigger DB load only when methods like `each`, `to_a`, `map` etc. a called. That is, only when user requests results of the query.

Having that in mind, you could imagine what is going to happen next to the object. Maybe there are such trigger methods? At least, you could always add them

```
obj.method1.load!
obj.method1.method2.load!
```

Comment: The problem between the ActiveRecord tricks, and my situation, is that the resource intensive portion is triggered when **no method** is called (obj.method1), i.e. when the object itself is returned, but it isn't triggered in the case of obj.method1.method2, where a method on the object is called.

Comment: Yes, my point is that you can reverse it and execute when trigger method _is_ called

Comment: I can't actually :( I am bounded only by how I can define my object, not how the methods are called on it. Meaning, I have to work with `obj.method1` because that is the way it will be used, I can't change that.

Comment: Then there is no way I can think of, sorry

Comment: Thanks for your help though, this is definitely a tough problem :(